# Call jQuery after some component was created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I call a function to create login modal in **index.html**

```
$('.login_btn').click(function(){LoginModal.open(); });
```

And I put LoginModal in **login.js**

```
var LoginModal = (function(){
  var thisObj;
  return thisObj = mapModalsFactory.create({
    attrs: {
      'id'   : 'login_modal',
      'class': ""
    },
    exitBtnClassName: false,
    callbacks: {
      onOpen: function($element){
        var $content = $(
          '<div>' +
            '<input type="text" id= "account" name="account" title="This is ToolTip"/>' +
          '</div>'
        );
        $element.append($content);
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

I encounter a problem, how do I call the `tooltip`?

In other word, where should I put the following code?

```
$('#account').tooltip();
```

More detail, If I click `login_btn`, then I type `$('#account').tooltip;` in develop console, it will work.

Comment: write the call code inside the `onOpen` function

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: is tooltip a function?

Comment: I call bootstrap tooltip.

Comment: I think you would have make sure to put it after `$element.append($content);` otherwise the element `account` won't be in the DOM when you call the method.

Comment: Yeah, I put `$('#account').tooltip();` after that. But seems it still can't find it.

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: I found out~ I should type `$content.find('#account').tooltip();`